# Web2py how to retrieve auth_user rows

Tags: python, database, web2py

I created the user by using basic Auth of Web2py

**below is the code**

```
from gluon.tools import Auth, Crud, Service, PluginManager, prettydate
auth = Auth(db)
crud, service, plugins = Crud(db), Service(), PluginManager()

## create all tables needed by auth if not custom tables
auth.define_tables(username=False, signature=False)
```

however the DAL seems can't recognize the basic auth table, how can I retrieve single or multiple rows data/row of users in **auth_user** table?????

Comment: You can access records in `db.auth_user` the same as any other table. Please show the code you are using to access records as well as the error you receive.

Comment: hi @Anthony yes I already tried that and as I said the db.auth_user is unrecognizable by DAL. The error message is here "AttributeError: 'DAL' object has no attribute 'auth_user'"

Comment: We need to know more about the code you are using to access `db.auth_user`. Exactly where is the above code, and does the code accessing `db.auth_user` come after the above?

Comment: @Anthony the following code below is the method i use to retrieve the user
_
def xx():
    tenants = db(db.auth_user).select(db.auth_user.ALL)


    return locals() _

Comment: As long as the code in your post is in a (non-conditional) model file and the code in your comment is in a controller, you shouldn't be getting that error. So, there must be something else about the structure of your app code that we're not seeing. I suggest you pack a minimal app that reproduces the problem and post it on the web2py Google Group.